# How to define field metadata in vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am trying to create a class where I want to determine the type of data shown in the field.
So I am thinking to attach custom metadata with the UI component (eg. TextField) to specify the metadata properties like: DataType, size, readOnly, etc..
So I could later use it to determine e.g. if TextField is bound to an Interger or a String or a CustomType.....

Could you suggest how to achieve this in Vaadin (using it for UI) or even in core java?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at vaadin fieldgroup: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.itembinding.html. If you bind everything with it, you will know the type of properties as well as the fields.

Comment: Can you give an example? I need to know field metadata at runtime like what is the data type of a particular field, maxSize, ReadOnly etc stuff set in code. Assume that we have a TextField, say 't1', which will show "Integer"'s value. So how to define its metadata to specify that 't1' has dataType Integer and readOnly ==true ? –